# plot line won't colored

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Here is my code

I don't know why the plot line won't colored and `geom_vline()` won't work.

This is the link for data source

https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1i4FHyp4hn-7PShKnaBqKAGhwcXvehjM8

```r
library(dplyr)  
library(devtools)
library(skimr)

data = read.csv('did_house.csv')
data = cbind(data['Period'],data['HouseIndexYoY'],data['North'])
skim(data, Period, HouseIndexYoY, North)


data = data %>%
  mutate(post2016 = Period >= 2016, 
         Location = North >= 1)

ggplot(data, aes(as.Date(Period), HouseIndexYoY,group = North)) +
  stat_summary(geom = 'line') +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 2016) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "year" , date_labels = "%Y") +
  theme_minimal()
```

It was expected to be like kind of this plot:

[image]

But my result plot like this

[image]

thanks for anyone read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
library(lubridate)
data = data %>%
  mutate(post2016 = Period >= 2016, 
         Location = North >= 1,
         Period = lubridate::dmy(Period))


ggplot(data, aes(Period, HouseIndexYoY,group = North, color = as.factor(North))) +
  stat_summary(geom = 'line') +
  geom_vline(xintercept = dmy("01-01-2016")) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "year" , date_labels = "%Y") +
  theme_minimal()
```

Comment: I try your whole answer except switch the `Period = as.Date(Period)` in `mutate()` . Then it works. Do Appreciate. Thanks for help

Comment: You're welcome. Please check the question resolved checkmark on the left if your question is answered.